# XCode crashes while trying to open Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to use realm file from the old project with the new one.

On startup I'm checking if the realm file exists in Documents directory and if it doesn't I'm just copying realm file from the bundle to the Documents directory.

This part (copying) works but if I try to open this new realm file, XCode just crashes although this file is definitely in the Documents directory (I checked).

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
let realmURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("realdata.realm")

var defConfig = Realm.Configuration()
defConfig.readOnly = true
defConfig.fileURL = realmURL
realm = try! Realm(configuration: defConfig)
```

This file exists, and I was able to open this with RealmBrowser from the Documents directory. File permissions wasn't changed (read/write). I'm using Realm/RealmSwift 2.10.2.

Also I've tried to create new realm, and it worked ok.

Comment: Does Xcode crash, or does your application?

Comment: Actually both (except for Simulator)

Comment: That's unusual. Can you file a ticket at our GitHub issue tracker (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues), and enclose a reproduction case? If you do so, please also include the version of Xcode.

Comment: same happens for me,app doesnt crash but xcode does...wtf is with xcode :(